# CSS Strange hover behavior

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a html like this;

```
<div id = "header">
        <a href ="#">Panel</a>
        <ul class="headermenu">
            <li><a href="">asdas</a></li>
            <li><a href="">asdasd</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

and css like this;

```
*{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    font-family: "Open Sans",Arial, Verdana;
    font-weight:100;
}

ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

div#header{
 margin:40px;   
}

div#header a{
    color:#B2B4B8;
    line-height:40px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}


.headermenu li{
    float:left;
}

.headermenu li a{
    display:block;
    margin-left:20px;
    font-size:12px;
}

.headermenu li a:hover{
    color:#000;
}

.headermenu{
    float:right;
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

I could not apply white color to hover of a of ul which has a class named headermenu, using `.headermenu li a:hover`

However I can apply this hover using `div#header .headermenu li a:hover`.

WHY? The all other syles are applied under .headermenu selector, but hover could not why?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbr5wbex/3/)

Comment: If you can not provide a more specific selector, use !important:
`.headermenu li a:hover { color: #000 !important; }`

Comment: it works. but why should i need this?

Comment: As @Lee mentioned, the ID selector takes presedence over a class selector.

Comment: You could also do `#header ul li a { color: #000; }`

Comment: As a last note, you should probably use ID for headermenu. I guess you will not have multiple header menus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `div#header a{` is setting the color, and an ID element will always take precedence over any class based element.

So your class based hover line, is being ignored.

Comment: Should not "div#header a{" set the color of a tags? It should not set the color of hover of a

Comment: It's not setting the hover colour, it's that your attempt of doing the hover colour is being ignored, because there's an ID for the entire tag is taking precedence. You should remove the ID based rule, and use a class based rule instead.

Comment: But why it is ignored? The other attributes i used is not ignored under .headermenu

Comment: Because you haven't used them in the ID class. You have `color:#B2B4B8;line-height:40px;display:block;float:left;` in the ID. You've got `display:block;margin-left:20px;font-size:12px;` in your CLASS style. These aren't being duplicated, and so are set. I may not have explained that in the best way, sorry.

Comment: i did not understand very much, but i guess your answer is right

Comment: The best way to think about it is you have four states, `:active`, `:focus`, `:hover` and `:visited`. Each of these can have styles applied. You could have a different colour set to each of these. However if you then have a colour set to the ID of the element you're adding these to, that will always be used.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to selector specificity. Your ID element has higher specificity than the class element and since both of them determine the color of your element, ID takes precedence.

More details:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

I found this very helpful when learning about css rules:
http://specificity.keegan.st/

Answer (score 0):

just add !important in your hover css

.headermenu li a:hover{ color:#000 !important; }

or try this:

div#header .headermenu li a:hover{ color:#000;}